# Can you customise foreign key names in self referencing entities in entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Some of the entities in my application have 4 audit properties on them:

```
    public virtual DateTime WhenAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? WhenUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual User AddedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

I am using a code first approach and have the following extension method to map the user properties:

```
    public static void MapAuditFields<T>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> configuration) where T : class, IAuditable
    {
        configuration.HasOptional<User>(e => e.AddedBy)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("AddedByUserId"));
        configuration.HasOptional<User>(e => e.UpdatedBy)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("UpdatedByUserId"));
    }
```

This is working fine in most cases, but not on the User class, which of course has a recursive relationship with itself. I have seen various posts on the internet suggesting that entity framework has a bug when you try to customise join table column names in this scenario, for example:

[Self-referencing many-to-many recursive relationship code first Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125052/self-referencing-many-to-many-recursive-relationship-code-first-entity-framework)

and

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f058097d-a0e7-4393-98ef-3b13ab5b165d/code-first-sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element-exception-when-generating-schema?forum=adonetefx

The error I am getting is "Sequence contains more than one matching element".

Does anyone know if this has been fixed in entity framework 6?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WithMany()` instead of `WithOptionalDependent()` as a user can add or update multiple other users

Class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User AddedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API calls:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional( u => u.AddedBy )
            .WithMany()
            .Map( fkamc => fkamc.MapKey( "AddedByUserId" ) );

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional( u => u.UpdatedBy )
            .WithMany()
            .Map( fkamc => fkamc.MapKey( "UpdatedByUserId" ) );
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but unfortunately this gives the same error.

Comment: ok, hmm, strange. Could you please share how you are mapping the audit fields on your other entities?

Comment: I just threw this together as a demo; I don't have other entities for this

Comment: I'm getting very strange behaviour here. This is the start of the project so I have only got 2 entities, User and Address. I have just removed the audit columns from Address, and still can't get your solution to work, but my original mapping works. When I re-add the audit columns to Address I then get the original error again.

Comment: I am now thinking that this is nothing to do with the recursive relationship. The ""Sequence contains more than one matching element" error is thrown whenever I map 2 entities with audit columns using the mapping code I have already posted. Thankyou for your help. I'm guessing I should probably start a different thread.

Comment: You should still use `.WithMany()` in those scenarios as well

Comment: Ok great. Have revisited this and changed all similar mappings throughout the model to use .WithMany() and now it works. If you are ever in Bristol England I owe you a drink :)  I have to admit I don't find this api very intuitive. For .WithMany() to suddenly refer to the other side of the relationship seems a bit weird to me but maybe thats just because I am used to hibernate. Anyway, thankyou!