# Class With .NextVersion and .PreviousVersion Navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class with 2 circular references to its self, `.NextVersion`, and `.PreviousVersion`, that creates a "chain" of objects as declared below.  When trying to use `Add-Migration` to create the database I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'SqlMetaQuery.Model.ScriptVersion' and
>   'SqlMetaQuery.Model.ScriptVersion'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

```
public class ScriptVersion
{
    public Guid ScriptVersionId { get; set; }
    public Guid ScriptId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ScriptVersion NextVersion { get; set; }
    public ScriptVersion PreviousVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I found several answers to similar questions that say to use `.HasOptional` and `.WithOptionalDependant` to resolve the associations. This works for **one** of the navigation properties, but fails when I try to do it for the 2nd navigation property.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ScriptVersion>()
            .HasOptional(v => v.NextVersion)
            .WithOptionalDependent(v => v.PreviousVersion);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ScriptVersion>()
            .HasOptional(v => v.PreviousVersion)
            .WithOptionalDependent(v => v.NextVersion);
```

> The navigation property 'PreviousVersion' declared on type
>   'SqlMetaQuery.Model.ScriptVersion' has been configured with
>   conflicting foreign keys.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033924/creating-a-double-linked-list-in-entity-framework

Comment: Is that question implying that I only need to configure one of the navigation properties?  When I do that, the migration is created without errors, but running it in to the database doesn't create the database structure I would expect.

Comment: Specifically, the ScriptVersion table only has a field for PreviousVersionId, no NextVersionId; and it needs to be nullable, but is created as required.

Comment: Yeah, that was a slight variation. Was thinking you might add MapKeys to both as a possible workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878457/can-you-customise-foreign-key-names-in-self-referencing-entities-in-entity-frame

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the entity but here is a solution. The trick is to add one or more additional "fake" properties to make the job.

**Entity**

```
public class ScriptVersion
{
    private ScriptVersion _nextVersion;
    private ScriptVersion _previousVersion;

    public Guid ScriptVersionId { get; set; }
    public Guid ScriptId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ScriptVersion NextVersion
    {
        get { return _nextVersion; }
        set
        {
            _nextVersion = value;
            if (_nextVersion != null && _nextVersion.PreviousVersion != this)
            {
                _nextVersion.PreviousVersion = this;
            }
        }
    }

    public ScriptVersion PreviousVersion
    {
        get { return _previousVersion; }
        set
        {
            _previousVersion = value;
            if (_previousVersion != null && _previousVersion.NextVersion != this)
            {
                _previousVersion.NextVersion = this;
            }
        }
    }

    internal ScriptVersion InternalNextVersion
    {
        get { return NextVersion; }
    }

    internal ScriptVersion InternalPreviousVersion
    {
        get { return PreviousVersion; }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ScriptVersion>()
    .HasOptional(v => v.NextVersion)
    .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.InternalPreviousVersion);

modelBuilder.Entity<ScriptVersion>()
    .HasOptional(v => v.PreviousVersion)
    .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.InternalNextVersion);
```