# How to implement a self-referencing many-to-many relations in .NET EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core

I am making a web application as a social network and I have a problem at the stage of creating models at EF Core (code-first, SQL Server).

I need to make the ability to add to friends for users. So, I am trying to establish a connection like "self referencing many-to-many". I saw how you can solve this problem by creating an additional array in the class, but is there any way to get around this "crutch"?

Here is my code of my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // ... Other properties

    public ICollection<UserFriend> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the `UserFriend` class:

```
public class UserFriend
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int FriendId { get; set; }
    public User Friend { get; set; }
}
```

Also here is my `DbContext` and its `OnModelCreating` settings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriend>()
                .HasKey(i => new { i.UserId, i.FriendId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriend>()
                .HasOne(c => c.User)
                .WithMany(w => w.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriend>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Friend)
                .WithMany(w => w.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.FriendId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

Comment: What so bad to have the public ICollection<UserFriend> Friends { get; set; } in your class?

Comment: That's does not work, because you need to set up relationships between tables and it turns out that we have a self-referencing many-to-many relationship

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125052/self-referencing-many-to-many-recursive-relationship-code-first-entity-framework ?

Comment: This method does not work in EF Core

Answer (score 0):

Your collection in User should be of the type Friend and not UserFriend. Also make it virtual:

```
public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends {get;set;}
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake with the name "Friends", but with the indication the virtual does not work anyway.